# AngularJS Caching a REST request

Tags: javascript, rest, caching, angularjs

I'm new to angularJS and have a question about caching etc.

I have a wizard with two steps, I want to be able to click back and next and have the forms still filled out as the user had them.

In my page1Partial i have this:

```
<li ng-repeat="pick in picks | orderBy:orderProperty">
<b><span ng-bind="pick.name"/></b>
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="pick.checked" ng-click="updateBasket(pick)">
</li>
```

When i go to the next page, then click back the checkboxs are cleared, and its because my RESful call to a java service is called again. How can I cache this response?

From my controller, this hits my REST web service every time.

```
$scope.picks = Pick.query();
```

My service

```
angular.module('picksService', ['ngResource']).
    factory('Pick', function ($resource) {
        return $resource('rest/picks/:id', {}, {
            'save': {method: 'PUT'}
        });
    });
```

Comment: Set the configuration property cache to true with $http object

Comment: where abouts do i set that? is that somewhere in my service?

Comment: Try using the approach suggested in the answer by shaunlim to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12772255/angularjs-using-shared-servicewith-resource-to-share-data-between-controller

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Since 1.1.2 ([commit](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/af89daf4641f57b92be6c1f3635f5a3237f20c71)), all the $httpConfig options are directly exposed in $resource action objects:

```
return {
  Things: $resource('url/to/:thing', {}, {
    list : {
      method : 'GET',
      cache : true
    }
  })
 };
```

Answer (score 10):

if you replace `$resource` with `$http` then you can directly use below code

```
$http({
    method: 'PUT',
    url: 'url',
    cache:true
});
```

Comment: I have not set this cache value explicitly. What is the default cache value in Angular 1.4.x? My first angularjs / CXF Rest app behaves differently on various browsers. Its not loading the newly created data in IE and seems like using old cache. But works fine on Firefox & Chrome.