# AngularJS, $resource and application cache

Tags: json, caching, angularjs, offline

I'm writting an application using angular and spring. It has to be able to work offline. After doing some research I found that application cache is the best way to go since I need to cache all the .css and .js files. The problem is that I can't get the data returned by spring and asked by the $resource object to be cached. When I turn off the server, static data are cached but I get a "GET error" in chrome's console about the .json he can't retrieve.

```
angular.module('MonService', ['ngResource']).
factory('Projet', function($resource){
return $resource('json/accueil');
});
```

I've tried something such as saving the response manually in a .json file then caching this file as well and use it as the source for the $resource but it seems long and complicated...

Or using localstorage, something like :

```
var cache, AmettreDansCache;
donne = {};

cache= window.localStorage.getItem('projets');

  if (!cache) {
   AmettreDansCache= $resource('json/accueil');
   window.localStorage.setItem('projets', JSON.stringify(AmettreDansCache));
   return AmettreDansCache
  }
 else{
    return angular.extend(donne, JSON.parse(cache));
 }
```

i don't think this is working, anyway what's the way to do it using application cache only ?

Comment: pls refer to the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15402867/angularjs-caching-a-rest-request/15403264#15403264

Comment: You might consider using something like breezejs for the caching parts.  http://www.breezejs.com/

Comment: Have you looked at the `cache` option on the $resource object?  http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.$resource

Answer (score 2):

There is a module built on top of resource that does caching, on both reading and writing data. You should check it out. It will keep a copy of your data on the clients browser and when failed to save (due to being offline) it will save it locally and keep retrying to save.

https://github.com/goodeggs/angular-cached-resource

There is also a small article about the module:

http://bites.goodeggs.com/open_source/angular-cached-resource/