# How to use 'cache: true' in angular for the given rest call?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, caching

I have never used cache in angular app. i am trying to use it. As given in the answer for the following question [Stackoverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15402867/angularjs-caching-a-rest-request)

I want to use `{cache:true}` in below rest calls? How could i use it ?
Do i need to add any dependency

```js
getBusinessUnits: function (e) {
              return $resource($rootScope.REST_URL + '/option/businessUnits')
                       .query().$promise;
            },
            getAllLegalEntities: function () {
              return $resource($rootScope.REST_URL + '/option/allLegalEntities')
                       .query().$promise;
            },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to redefine `query` action of the constructed resource object and add `cache` settings:

```
getBusinessUnits: function (e) {
  return $resource($rootScope.REST_URL + '/option/businessUnits', null, {
    query: {method:'GET', isArray:true, cache: true}
  }).query().$promise;
}
```

Comment: for the method getBusinessUnits it is working fine but for the
getLegalEntities: function (businessUnit, reqType) {
                return $resource($rootScope.REST_URL + '/option/legalEntities', null,{query:{method:'GET', isArray:true, cache:true}},{'businessUnit': businessUnit, 'reqType':reqType}).query().$promise;

            }
Its not fetching the data: 
getLegalEntities: function (businessUnit, reqType) {
                return $resource($rootScope.REST_URL + '/option/legalEntities',{cache: true}, {'businessUnit': businessUnit, 'reqType':reqType}).query().$promise;

            }

Comment: Ok i got it its working now like this:
getLegalEntities: function (businessUnit, reqType) {
                return $resource($rootScope.REST_URL + '/option/legalEntities',{'businessUnit': businessUnit, 'reqType':reqType},{ query: {method:'GET', isArray:true, cache: true}}).query().$promise;

            }

Comment: how would i know it is taking from the cache ??

Comment: [dfsq](http://stackoverflow.com/users/949476/dfsq)Thanks for your response....response time is very less after caching so its confirmed it is coming from cach.
Please help me in one more thing..is it possible to give some time to get it expired??

Comment: Sorry, didn't see your question. You can verify that cache is used if you make two `getBusinessUnits()` calls in the row and check developer tools for requests to `option/businessUnits` URL. There should be only one such request (and two without cache:true). If you want to clear cache you can do it like this:  `$cacheFactory.get('$http').remove($rootScope.REST_URL + '/option/businessUnits')` (inject $cacheFactory service).