# Sharing resources between controllers in Angular.js

Tags: javascript, rest, model-view-controller, angularjs

Simple question.

I have this resource:

```
var Company = $resource("/company/:_id", {_id: "@_id"});
```

That I want to share between different controllers.

Right now, I am copy-pasting things around but I am still not at the point where I want to add more code and use [angular shared services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12772255/angularjs-using-shared-servicewith-resource-to-share-data-between-controller)

Any other option ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just put in a service or factory.

```
angular.module("myApp", []).
  factory("CompanyResource", function ($resource) {
    return $resource("/company/:_id", {_id: "@_id"}); 
  });
```

and then you can use it in the controller with

```
function MapCtrl($scope, $resource, $location, CompanyResource) {
   ...
   CompanyResource.query();
   ...
}
```

Note that you do not need the $ sign in front of the factory name.

Comment: hi umur , is it okay if I append $ sign at CompanyResource. $CompanyResource ?

Comment: @kebyang No it's not OK. Dollar sign ($) as a prefix is reserved for angular services.