# How to share search functionality between controllers in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have 3 controllers that all do a paged search of data.  They use different base URLs but have the same basic functionality.  They have the variables offset, pageSize, etc and methods search, next, prev, etc.

What would be the proper way to share this functionality between the controllers?

I'm thinking of using a service but I don't know if that's the wrong way to go about doing it or not.

Comment: Yes, you must use a service, is the best way to do it.

Comment: The canonical way to share any resources between controllers is through a service.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sharing resources between controllers in Angular.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15627161/sharing-resources-between-controllers-in-angular-js)

Comment: I agree with @JesúsQuintana, use a `service`

Answer (score 1):

Services is the correct way to share functionality between controllers. Factories are for more complicated use than what seems to be your need. A simple service goes like this:

```
myApp.service('mySvc',  function() {
  this.myFct=function() {
    //...                       
  }
});
```