# Sharing a restangular resource between controllers

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Based on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12772255/angularjs-using-shared-servicewith-resource-to-share-data-between-controller) I've implemented the following (using Restangular):

```
    app.factory('Account', function(Restangular) {
      var _account;

      return {
        get: function(id, success, failure) {
          // If we've already retrieved an account, return that
          if (angular.isDefined(_account)) {
            console.log('local');
            success(_account);

          // Otherwise request the resource and store it for subsequent requests
          } else { 
            console.log('server');
            Restangular.one('accounts', id).get().then(
              // Success
              function(account) {
                _account = account;
                success(_account);
              },
              // Failure
              function(response) {
                if (angular.isDefined(failure)) {
                  failure(response);
                }
              }
            );
          }
        }
      }
    });
```

I'm using it like this from my controllers:

```
Account.get(1, function(account) {
    $scope.account = account;
});
```

The problem is that because the calls are asyc all of the calls check _account and find it to be null and so make a server call, then I get a) multiple server calls for the same thing and b) unlinked models.

If I alter the code to return the 'promise' immediately, I find I can't edit any text fields that I'm binding with ng-model..

Is there any way around this? am I doing something wrong? as far as I can tell the original thread should suffer the same problem..?

Comment: If I return the promise? immediately:
_account = Restangular.one('accounts', id).get();
success(_account);

The UI renders fine, showing the correct data from the resource, and any requests after the first one use the local object, but if I have this under two controllers:

<input type="text" ng-model="account.name" />

If I try to edit either of them, none of my key presses appear?

Comment: I think this is the problem: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1827

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my (rough) solution:

There appears to be a bug with Angular and promises, detailed here:
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1827

The patch hasn't been pulled into the master branch yet, so as a workaround to my issue whilst not relying on sending promises to the view:

```
    app.factory('Account', function(Restangular) {
      var _account;
      var _promise;
      var _callbacks = new Array();

      return {
        get: function(id, success, failure) {
          // If we have a local account, immediately call success
          if (angular.isDefined(_account)) {
            success(_account);
          }

          // If we've already obtained a promise, add to callbacks to be notified
          // when the promise resolves
          else if (angular.isDefined(_promise)) {
            _callbacks.push(success);
          }

          // Make a server request
          else { 
            console.log('request from server');
            _callbacks.push(success);
            _promise = Restangular.one('accounts', id).get().then(
              function(account) {
                _account = account;
                // Fulfill promises
                angular.forEach(_callbacks, function(callback) {
                  callback(_account);
                }); 
                _promise = null;
              } 
            );
          }
        }
      }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Can you please also give us an example of usage in a Controller? Thanks